# Oracle Application Express plugin development using v4.2.2

Tags: plugins, plsql, oracle-apex

I am working on some Oracle APEX Plugin development and wonder whether the following requirement is possible.

I basically would like to be able, via a plugin, create a form with say six page items, where two of those page items might be LOVs, another two are page items are text fields, where users have to enter values and the remaining two are display items only.

Based on this form requirement, I want to be able to upload/install this plugin within other Oracle Application Express apps/schemas, so when installed within other apps, this plugin is rendered within a region and the data is stored within a table in that schema, but using the form described above.

Can this be achieved building a plugin in Oracle APEX, and if so, how?

Comment: You don't need a plugin for that - just create the form with the itesms you need. All those item types are already supported by Apex. More info on plugins: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/application-express/apex-plug-ins-182042.html

Comment: Hey Jeffrey, appreciate the feedback and info but what I would like to achieve is to have one location to build a form with fields in one application and then re-use this same form with fields within another application but don't actually want to re-build again. Want to take the master form page and apply it to several other applications, with different workspace ids. Hope this make sense and this being the reason for a possibly using a plugin. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if a plugin can do all that... maybe someone else can answer definitively.

Comment: You can copy a region from one page to another, in the same application or in another application. Also, you can put a region on page zero (0) and show it on multiple pages using a condition.

Comment: Hi, know about page 0 but unsure how one copies a region from one app to another app with defferent workspace ids? Also, it'not just the region I need, I actually require all page contents. Thanks again.

Comment: I'd create a stock application with the pages and regions that need to be replicated, export that, and import it into the other workspaces that need it. Then, when developing an application, I'd copy the regions and/or pages as necessary from that stock application.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp I think you should post that as an answer. Using a "master" application to contain your reusable components will come closest to what OP wants. Afaik you can't create the requested functionality through a plugin. It'd take a region type plugin, but then there'd be no page items defined, which would not work anyway.

Comment: Why do you think that page items defined in region type plugin won't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a stock application with the pages and regions that need to be replicated, export that, and import it into the other workspaces that need it. Then, when developing an application, copy the regions and/or pages as necessary from that stock application.